# How to debug / correctly setup git-multimail

Tags: python, git, githooks, post-receive-email

I would like to use [git-multimail](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail) as post receive hook in one of my git repositories (no gitolite used). Unfortunately, I cannot get it work, and I have hardly any experience using Python.

### What I did so far:

1. I added the following block to the `project.git/config` file:

```
[multimailhook]
    mailingList = email@example.com
    from = email@example.com
    envelopeSender = email@example.com
    mailer = smtp
    smtpServer = smtp.mydomain.com
    smtpUser = myUser
    smtpPass = myPassword
```

Please note that I do not know whether "smtp", which is defined in the `mailer` variable, is installed on my machine.

2. I copied the current `git_multimail.py` file into `project.git/hooks`.
3. I created a `project.git/hook/post-receive` file with the following content. The file is executable, I copied this from https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/blob/master/git-multimail/post-receive.example

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import git_multimail

config = git_multimail.Config('multimailhook')

try:
    environment = git_multimail.GenericEnvironment(config=config)
    #environment = git_multimail.GitoliteEnvironment(config=config)
except git_multimail.ConfigurationException:
    sys.stderr.write('*** %s\n' % sys.exc_info()[1])
sys.exit(1)

mailer = git_multimail.choose_mailer(config, environment)

git_multimail.run_as_post_receive_hook(environment, mailer)
```

### What happens:

When I push a change, a file `project.git/hooks/git_multimail.pyc` is created, but no email is sent.

Doing a configuration test using `GIT_MULTIMAIL_CHECK_SETUP=true python git_multimail.py` as described on https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/blob/master/doc/troubleshooting.rst tells me that `git-multimail seems properly set up`

Is there a way to log something like an output of the script? What can I do to find out what is not working? Are there even errors in my files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For git-multimail related questions, don't hesitate to ask directly on [git-multimail's bug tracker](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/issues). Anyway, glad to see you answered your own question ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `post-receive.example` is by far not the simplest way to set up `git_multimail.py`: as the header of post-receive.example script says:

> The simplest way to use git-multimail is to use the script
>   git_multimail.py directly as a post-receive hook, and to configure it
>   using Git's configuration files and command-line parameters.

In other words, just

```
cp /path/to/git_multimail.py /path/to/project.git/hooks/post-receive
```

and you're all set (since you already have `project.git/config` filled-in). See [Invocation in git-multimail's README](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail#invocation) for a bit more detail.

(note: admitedly, the doc is not so clear for beginners, [I'll try to improve that when I get time](https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/issues/175))

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, the error was probably as little as it could be. I did just one very little mistake in the post receive hook file: The `sys.exit(1)` command is not indented.

So, the WRONG version from my question:

```
try:
    environment = git_multimail.GenericEnvironment(config=config)
except git_multimail.ConfigurationException:
    sys.stderr.write('*** %s\n' % sys.exc_info()[1])
sys.exit(1)
```

CORRECT is (compare last line):

```
try:
    environment = git_multimail.GenericEnvironment(config=config)
except git_multimail.ConfigurationException:
    sys.stderr.write('*** %s\n' % sys.exc_info()[1])
    sys.exit(1)
```

Like I said, I hardly know Python, so I did not pay attention to the indents. After correcting this, the email was sent, so feel free to use the above steps as a little tutorial for setting up git-multimail the "easiest" way. (I did not find a tutorial for this exact solution.)

Comment: You're making it more complex than it should be. No Python involved to set up git-multimail, just copy or link the file to hooks/post-receive.